# Copy large number of small blobs with AzCopy

Tags: azure, azcopy, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to do an incremental copy of ca. 500.000 blobs from one storage account to another.

However, it seems that if I do not specify a /Pattern: parameter, AzCopy just hangs forever, never finishes.. (I actually stopped the process after about 15 min).

Is half a million (potentially up to 5 million) blobs too much for AzCopy to handle, or am I missing something here?

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
AzCopy /Source:<src>/documents /SourceKey:<srcKey> /Dest:<dest>/documents /DestKey:<deskKey> /S /XO /Y
```

Adding the /pattern parameter solves it, but I'd like a complete copy of all blobs in the container.

I have to add, it managed to copy all the blobs already, it is the subsequent runs that fail, when it has to "figure out" which blobs have been added since the last full backup..

Comment: I would recommend tracing the request/response through something like Fiddler so that you know what AzCopy is doing in this scenario where you think it is hanging.

Comment: Fiddler cannot really show the communication since it's https, but I can see a constant bandwidth usage from AzCopy in the resource monitor, ca. 200kB/s upload and 400kB/s download to blob.am3prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net. So I am assuming it is doing the comparison of blobs in source and destination..?

Comment: You could decrypt HTTPS traffic in Fiddler (http://www.enhanceie.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp). I think your suspicion is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, looking into the traffic with Fiddler, it revealed that AzCopy is doing head requests for all blobs in the target storage account, one-by-one... 

HEAD /documents/152185?timeout=300 HTTP/1.1

I was under the (incorrect) impression that AzCopy does these operations "asynchronously", that is only between the source and destination storages, not involving the client machine azcopy runs on.. That seems not to be the case..

Answer (score 0):

Which version of AzCopy are you using? I guess this issue has been fixed for many releases... Several versions ago, AzCopy needs to list all the blobs to be downloaded before starting transfer; currently AzCopy is able to do listing and transfer simultaneously.

For download latest version of AzCopy and find more information, please refer to http://aka.ms/azcopy .

Comment: Version 3.2.0.93. 
It may be doing listing and transfer simultaneously, but it is doing the listing of the destination blobs one at a time, as you can see in my comment to the original post.

Comment: It's by design. If option /XO or /XN is specified, AzCopy needs to get target blobs one by one in order to fetch their LastModifiedTime.